# Inner product space involving random vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, random-variables, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators

I've come across the following notation in a paper:

> Let $L : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a self-adjoint operator. Suppose $X$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\langle LX, X \rangle$ is a random variable.

How exactly is $\langle LX, X \rangle$ a random variable defined on an inner product space here? We can represent $L$ as a $n\times n$ matrix. Is it then correct to assume that

$$\langle LX, X \rangle = \langle X, LX \rangle =(LX)^TX,$$

which would give a random variable in this sense.

Comment: Any function of a random variable is another random variable.

Comment: Sure. I was more so interested in how the inner product is defined. For example, a property of $L$ is positive semi-definiteness, which can be proved (among other ways) using the Spectral Theorem, i.e. $L = \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(L)} \lambda P_{\lambda}$. But it wouldn't make much sense if the inner product isn't defined as above.

Comment: The inner product here is the pointwise inner product of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the usual sense.